# How do I convert a Stream<ArrayofObject> to List<Object>?

Tags: java, arrays, object, java-stream

I'm new to streams and need to convert Stream

```
public PayeeFacilityResponse searchPayeeFacility(String providerTaxID) {
        PayeeFacilityResponse payeeFacilityResponse = new PayeeFacilityResponse();
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(providerTaxID)) {
            Doc doc = null;
            try {
                doc = getPayeeFacilityDoc(providerTaxID);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }


            Stream<ArrayOfPayeeFacility> facilityStream = doc.objects("//*[local-name()='PayeeFacilities']", ArrayOfPayeeFacility.class);
            List<PayeeFacility> payeeFacilityList = new ArrayList<>();
            //need to convert facilityStream to ArrayofPayeeFacility
            ArrayOfPayeeFacility arrayOfPayeeFacility = new ArrayOfPayeeFacility();


            payeeFacilityResponse.setPayeeFacilities(arrayOfPayeeFacility);
        }
        return payeeFacilityResponse;
    }
```

This is ArrayOfPayeeFacility

```
public class ArrayOfPayeeFacility {

    protected List<PayeeFacility> payeeFacility;

    public ArrayOfPayeeFacility() {
    }

    public List<PayeeFacility> getPayeeFacility() {
        if (this.payeeFacility == null) {
            this.payeeFacility = new ArrayList();
        }

        return this.payeeFacility;
    }
}
```

How would I convert facilityStream to List?  ArrayofPayeeFacility contains List

Comment: That depends on `ArrayOfPayeeFacility`. Please post a complete example

Comment: Usually a stream contains multiple objects. How do you think this should be handeled when converting to a single ArrayOfPayeeFacility?